# Updated Jsp Is Not Being Translated Into Java File In iplanet Web Server

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, iplanet

I am new to an `iPlanet` web server. There is a requirement for my project: I need to debug it by placing: `<%System.out.println("this working fine Kind of messages"+a);%>`.

I have updated some part of my `JSP` to debug whether the corresponding values are being populated from back-end application correct or not. When I placed `JSP` and run an application from the browser, I'm getting a blank page, which means it is not translated properly. I checked and restarted the server as well, but I'm still facing the same issue and the `.java` is generated fine, but without content in it. Please suggest any right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue, after lots of experimenting like.

1. tried deleting particular generated .java file, did not solve that issue. but
2. path of generated folder were /generated/org/apache/jsp/*.java and their corresponding *.class, came till /generated/ dir and took backup of existing org dir and deleted it. once again I tried hitting URL on a browser to get that particular JSP result,I glad to see that my sysout are printing over webserver's console.

overall My suggestion is just to delete that generated *.java and *.class files iPlanet will regenerate whenever you request it.